# Hamiltonian Cycles (See image) - Script Possible?

Tags: edges

[image: Hamiltonian Cycles Examples]

(More info in the comments below)

Cube, Tetra, Octa, and Pyramid (x4) / Half an Octa (hedron)

These were simple enough.  The more complex the poly (ex: Cuboctahedron or Dodecahedron or, if you're feeling more ambition, Icosahedron or Truncated Icosahedron - Soccer Ball)

Is there an easy way to figure these out?  Perhaps a python script or mathematical formulas?

The tracings don't cross, or connect - there than as one continuous line.

These are the beginner level tracings.

Could be interesting at more complex levels.

(I've seen it done elsewhere with a a truncated icosahedron (see comments below).  That's what got me thinking about it.

Comment: Hello. Could you define more clearly which outlines you want (or don't want)?

Comment: do you need just the outer shape or what?

Comment: Blender supplies the shapes (Dodecahedron, Truncated Icosahedron).  I think those two would be the most interesting.

If generic code applicable to any polyhedron to determine the likelihood (some may not) and from there, examples) those two, specifically, among others, generically speaking, would be nice.

If generic code is problematic, then, those two just the same.

Comment: As you can see in the image, they can be used on the original polyhedron or perhaps in other creative ways, such as via array, spun, via Empty I'm thinking.

Comment: Try the extra objects addon, under Math Function in the Add -> Mesh menu select Regular Solid and play around

Comment: Hamiltonian circuit is the term that applies here.

Examples: (Including Dodecahedron)

http://old.nationalcurvebank.org/hamiltoncircuit/hamiltoncircuit.htm

Comment: The example I had in mind:  Truncated Icosahedron (Soccer Ball)

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=hamilton+circuit+truncated+icosahedron&qpvt=Hamilton+Circuit+Truncated+Icosahedron&form=IQFRML&first=1&tsc=ImageHoverTitle

Comment: More examples here: (including cuboctahedron and others)

http://home.iae.nl/users/zonneve/

No scripts.  but, demonstrations. One example refers to a script written, but, I think it was POV-Ray which only seems to work for generating images:

https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/various/cycle-hamiltonien-sur-icosaedre-tronque

Comment: While it lasts: Hamiltonian Platonics (Blend File)

https://pasteall.org/blend/bbaf26fb13f349368c99a6c55d2425c2

with help from this: (Slide 7):

https://www.slideserve.com/zada/hamiltonian-cycles-on-symmetrical-graphs